# Building dynamic variables for menus in Python

Tags: python, variables, menu, lcd, dynamic-variables

I'm using an excellent [menu structure function from Github](https://github.com/sleeepyjack/RPi_AdafruitLCD_Menu) which is powering a small LCD. The menus contain top (parent) elements and sub elements, and I want to build the sub-elements dynamically. Currently they're static and work like this:

```
top5 = menu.topElement("< top5         >", "STRING", "        v")
sub25 = menu.subElement("Bus>Times", "STRING", "this is a really long scroll string")

menu.addSubElement(top5, sub25)
```

I have another function which will output the text of the required sub-element menus. What I can't fathom is how to generate sub26, sub27 etc. dynamically (there could be 1, or 7, or any number really), and each of them will contain different content. I am absolutely stuck!

I'm trying to work on a dict but my brain can't understand how this will output a dynamic variable name (incremental), with dynamic content attributed to it (where xx is dynamic below)

```
subXX = menu.subElement("Top 5> More", "STRING", "XX")
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use lists?

```
sub[i] = menu.subElement("text", "STRING", "XX")
```

where `i` is any number.

Comment: You were downvoted, but this is the objectively correct solution to the problem. `exec` is (a) dangerous; (b) completely inappropriate - it takes the OP's design for granted, when it's just wrong. You are correct; this is exactly what lists are for.